Check whether a string value is formula or range or constant
I have a very specific use case where I need to read value input in the data validation field for each cell.
If the value is a list, then the value should be stored in the string as it is. However, if it is a range or a named range, then range should be deciphered and then value should be converted to a list and then stored.
For example, if the validations are "active, inactive", then permissible_values = "active, inactive"
If validation is "=Sheet1!A1:A4", then permissible_values = " Yes, No, Maybe, NA" if A1 = "Yes", A2 = "No", A3 = "Maybe" and A4 = "NA"
I've been able to read the value from the validation field, but how to decipher if the value in the string is a list or a range?
        Temp = Range(Cells(5, Counter).Address).Validation.Formula1
        Temp = Right(Temp, Len(Temp) - 1)
        Sheet1.Select
        Set Temp2 = Range(Temp)
        New_Sheet.Cells(Counter + 1, 3).Value = TJoin(";", Temp2)

I'm using above code to read the range value and create a single string out of it. But this won't work on static. Unable to form an if condition for this. Also, in the above code, if it is a range, then currently sheet is not a variable. I'm manually selecting Sheet1 in the code and then selecting the range. Can I make sheet selection also variable which can be done on the basis of value in the validation?

I can see this being quite difficult without a list of terms.  If you do have a list of terms you can loop/match or use a dictionary to quickly assess terms.  As for ranges, in the scenario of the previous sentence it is values that do not match.  You can't simply say "if ! is in string" because A1 and Sheets!A1 can be many items.

Wait, maybe i missed this or overlooked it when reading... =Sheet1!A1 versus active; if the = is in the string, that may be your key to determining which is a range.

Not a full answer, but you could try something along these lines.
Public Function get_validation_summary(rngCell As Range) As String

Dim v As Validation
Dim r As Range
Dim a() As Variant

Set v = rngCell.Validation

Set r = is_range((Right(v.Formula1, Len(v.Formula1) - 1)))

If Not r Is Nothing Then
    a = Application.Transpose(r)
    get_validation_summary = Join(a, ",")
Else
    get_validation_summary = v.Formula1
End If

End Function

Public Function is_range(strFormula As String) As Range

On Error GoTo eHandle:

Set is_range = Range(strFormula)

exit_function:

Exit Function

eHandle:

    Set is_range = Nothing
    GoTo exit_function
    
End Function


A bit like the other answer - but more condensed, as it checks for the equal-sign:
Public Function getValuesOfValidationlist(c As Range) As String
If Not c.Validation Is Nothing Then
    Dim strFormula As String
    strFormula = c.Validation.Formula1
    If Left(strFormula, 1) = "=" Then
        getValuesOfValidationlist = Join(Application.Transpose(Range(Mid(strFormula, 2))), ", ")
    Else
        getValuesOfValidationlist = strFormula
    End If
Else
   getValuesOfValidationlist = "no validation"
End If
End Function

You can call it like this:
New_Sheet.Cells(Counter + 1, 3).Value = getValuesOfValidationlist(ActiveSheet.cells(5,Counter))
And maybe it's worth reading How to avoid using select
